# Alignment of a TikZ environment with a minipage environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a `TikZ` environment with a `minipage` environment, and I would like them aligned at the top. I use the option `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` with the `TikZ` environment, and the the option `[t]` with the `minipage` environment.  The displays of the two environments are not aligned.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}


\begin{document}


\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{3.75in}
\raggedright{$\triangle\mathit{ABC}$ is a right triangle, and its right angle is at $C$. $\mathit{CP}$ is an altitude of it. What is the value of $x - y$?}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }$-30$ \\
\> \textbf{b.) }$-15$ \\
\> \textbf{c.) }0 \\
\> \textbf{d.) }15 \\
\> \textbf{e.) }30
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{-1.5cm}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (5,2);

%B is the intersection of the line through C that is perpendicular to $\overline{AC}$ and
%the line through A inclined at an angle of 30 degrees.
\path[name path=a_line_through_A_to_locate_B] (A) -- ($(A) +(-15:7)$);
\path[name path=a_line_through_C_perpendicular_to_AC_to_locate_B] (C) -- ($(C)!4.5cm!90:(A)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_line_through_A_to_locate_B and a_line_through_C_perpendicular_to_AC_to_locate_B, by=B}];
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;


%A right-angle mark is drawn at C.
\coordinate (U) at ($(C)!4mm!-45:(B)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(C)!(U)!(B)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(C)!(U)!(A)$);


\coordinate (P) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
\draw (C) -- (P);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
\coordinate (V) at ($(P)!4mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw (V) -- ($(P)!(V)!(A)$);
\draw (V) -- ($(P)!(V)!(C)$);


%The labels for A, B, and C are typeset.
\node (label_for_A) at ($(A)!3mm!-90:(B)$){$A$};
\node (label_for_B) at ($(B)!3mm!90:(A)$){$B$};
\node (label_for_P) at ($(P)!3mm!-90:(B)$){$P$};
\node (label_for_C) at ($(C)!-3mm!(P)$){$C$};



%The angle at A is labeled x.
\draw[blue] let \p1=($(A)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (-15:0.5) arc (-15:\n1:0.5);
\draw let \p1=($(A)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[font=\footnotesize, anchor={0.5*(\n1-15)-180}] at ({0.5*(\n1-15)}:0.5){$x$};

%An angle at C is labeled y.
\draw[blue] let \p1=($(C)-(P)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(C)-(B)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(C) +({\n1-180}:0.5)$) arc ({\n1-180}:\n2:0.5);
\draw let \p1=($(C)-(P)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(C)-(B)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in node[font=\footnotesize, anchor={0.5*(\n1-180+\n2)-180}] at ($(C) +({0.5*(\n1-180+\n2)}:0.5)$){$y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is because there is some whitespace in the upper part of your `tikzpicture`. I don't think removing it will make it *look* as if they are aligned. I think this one will have to be manually adjusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following line at the end of your tikzpicture:

```
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
```

reveals the bounding box of the picture:

[image: Result]

Two problems can be spoted:

1. Above the label $C$ in the figure there is a bit of space. This can be removed if you use `[inner sep=0pt]` for the node `(label_for_C)`
2. More important, option `[t]` of `minipage` does not align the content at the top of the "bounding box" of the minipage, but instead at the baseline of its top line. This can be solved by a little hack: to add `\vskip0pt` as the first content of the minipage. This way, the first "line" of the box is empty and you get the right alignment.

Using both tricks, the result is:

[image: Result2]

We can now remove the frame:

[image: Final result]

Comment: I did not know that `LaTeX` surrounded a `minipage` environment with white space.   You are telling me that putting`\vskip0pt` as the first command of the `minipage` eliminates the empty space.  That gives me the alignment that I wanted.  Thanks.  (Why do you call it a hack?)

Comment: @Adelyn No, there is not space around minipages. The explanation is about the "baseline" (an imaginary horizontal used to align all boxes in the same line). Each character has its own baseline, but a minipage and a tikz picture also have baselines. You can affect the baseline of tikz using the `baseline` option. For minipages you can use [b] or [t] options, but [t] does not work as expected, because it sets the baseline of the minipage as the baseline of the first line of text inside that minipage. This is why `\vskip0pt` is hack. It inserts a first "line" of 0 size at top of the minipage.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation.